# git pull over ssh gives wierd errors

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, git, bitbucket

This is my setup.

1. My git repository is in bitbucket
2. I have created keys on my remote aws ec2 server and kept it in `~/.ssh` folder
3. I then add the key via the ssh-agent on my remote server
4. Updated these keys on the bitbucket website.

When I login to my remote server and run `git pull` on my git repository everything works fine. **No issues here.**

But when I run the same the same via the cygwin bash on windows it gives me this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I do the following on my windows machine

```
ssh -i xyz.pem user@ip -t 'sudo sh deploy.sh'
```

Where the `deploy.sh`, **cd's** into my repository and does a `git pull`.

Why is this issue happening ? **Should I also keep these ssh keys on my windows machine?**
Any help will be invaluable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By running `sh` with `sudo`, you are effectively using the root's `.ssh` credentials to access the repo. Those do not match with the key you generated and added to bitbucket.

I wonder why you would need `sudo` in the first place, is the repo only writable by root? One option would be to add root's ssh key to bitbucket, or to refrain from using `sudo`.